# Neo4j runs very slow with non-unique index vs. using unique constraint

Tags: performance, neo4j, windows-10

Using Neo4j 3.3.2 on Windows 10 64 bit.
Running a simple query on nodes in a database with about 250,000 nodes total.

```
UNWIND {LIST} AS i MATCH (ig:Ingrd {name: i.NAME}) SET ig.cas = i.CAS
```

If I create the following index before initially loading the nodes and before running the above query it runs slow:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Ingrd(name)
```

If I drop that index and run the following it runs fast:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ig:Ingrd) ASSERT ig.name IS UNIQUE
```

Using the INDEX the query runs about 15 transactions/s

Using the CREATE CONSTRAINT the query runs about 7000 transactions/s

If I profile, the only difference is 'NodeIndexSeek' vs. 'NodeUniqueIndexSeek'.

Any ideas why it runs 400x slower?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Added images. Everything looks like it should be fine, but when run adding 1000 updates to the list to unwind, the unique constraint is 400x faster.

[image]

[image]

**Update2**: Run in one thread, it is reproducible if run multiple times back to back. Actual query edited above. The above index/constraint is the only one for this node.  For this node (Ingrd) the name field is actually unique so adding a constraint solved this specific issue, but it still exists for other nodes. Can reproduce for other nodes as well with non-unique search fields.

Comment: Can you provide images of the query plans (after expanding all elements) when you PROFILE both queries?

Comment: updated OP to include plans. They look fine but one runs 400x slower.

Comment: Make sure you run the queries a couple of times to get more precise metrics. The first run may not have that portion of the graph in pagecache, and the plan may not be cached. Are you still seeing a 400x difference?

Comment: Can you a add the statement that you actually run? Your plan is different from the statements you list. Do you have any other indexes / constraints? Is this running concurrently or single threaded?

Comment: Actual Statment: UNWIND {LIST} AS i MATCH (ig:Ingrd {name: i.NAME}) SET ig.cas = i.CAS     I can reproduce this after any cache would be filled.

Comment: This is run in one python thread using neo4j-driver v 1.5.3.  Also, the constrain is the only index/constraint on the node. I tested unique constraint because it was an option for this node as ig.name is in fact a unique field. The reason I asked this question is that I have other nodes that have non-unique indexed fields I search on. The problem appears there as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you see any performance differences from what you're currently seeing if you prefix the query with `CYPHER 3.2`?

Comment: I went back to the logs and this has been an issue for at least 4 months. I don't have logs older than that..

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem seems to be related to UNWIND. If I run a transaction and using parameters in batch transactions it works fine with a non-unique index.

```
UNWIND {LIST} AS i MATCH (ig:Ingrd {name: i.NAME}) SET ig.cas = i.CAS
```

is slow.

```
MATCH (ig:Ingrd {name: {NAME}}) SET ig.cas = {CAS)
```

is fast.

I switched to using UNWIND to try and improve performance. That does not work on non-unique indexes. Using UNWIND is >100x slower.

Comment: Neo4j seems to have fixed this bug in 3.3.4